# What cause this array value to change?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am going slightly crazy over a value changing in a multidimensional array even though assignment doesn't appear to happen. I am working on a program to find the longest common subsequence between two strings. To that end, I create an array of arrays whose dimensions are the lengths of the respective strings. I initialize the first row and column of the array to zeroes, but for some reason `arr[2][0]` becomes `1`. This happens in the first iteration of the outer for loop when `j=0` and `k=5`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    string a = "bird";
    string b = "turdbi";
    int aLen = a.length();
    int bLen = b.length();
    int arr[aLen][bLen];
    //initializing the multidimensional array
    for (int i=0;i<aLen;i++){
        arr[i][0]=0;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<bLen;i++){
        arr[0][i]=0;
    }
    int subsequence=0;
    for (int j=0;j<aLen;j++){ //(0,0) is the leftmost corner of the table, to compensate for additional row/col
        for(int k=0;k<bLen;k++){
            if (a.at(j)==b.at(k)){
                subsequence = arr[j][k]+1; //add one to upper diagonal
            }
            else {
                subsequence = max(arr[j+1][k],arr[j][k+1]); //find max value from adjacent cells'
            }
            //how does arr[2][0] ==1??
            arr[j+1][k+1]=subsequence;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger?

Comment: I'd guess that `j+1` and `k+1` are out of bounds at some point.

Comment: `int arr[aLen][bLen];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime variable or expression value.  If you used `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` which is standard, you would have a better chance of finding your error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's a GCC extension.

Comment: Your array size is [4][6], and you're saying that when you write to [1][6] weird stuff happens... I wonder why?

Comment: @immibis I know it's an extension, and wished it was off by default.  If that happened, then maybe the OP (and countless others who use this syntax) would find the issue and would never have to ask "what happened".  [See here -- out-of-bounds](https://ideone.com/i2cyD1)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Totally agree... The extension comes from C's VLA - which never ever should have made it into the standard there either. They rather should have standardised alloca instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments basically said it all. Your index are out of bounds when you do j + 1 and k + 1 when your limits for j < aLen and k < bLen.

As for why it happens, arrays are guaranteed to be stored sequentially in the memory. Hence when you create an array -> int a[2][3], what you are creating in the memory is this.

```
0 - a[0][0] -   
1 - a[0][1]  |--- a[0] == &a[0][0] (same type, same value)
2 - a[0][2] -
3 - a[1][0] -
4 - a[1][1]  |--- a[1] == &a[1][0] (same type, same value)
5 - a[1][2] -
```

&a[0][0], &a[0][1], &a[0][2], &a[1][0]... are pointers to int.
Hence every time the second subscript is incremented (in your case, k), we increment the pointer values by sizeof(int).

&a[0] and &a[1] are pointers to an array of 3 ints.
Meaning, every time the first subscript is incremented (in your case j), we increment the pointer values by sizeof(int) * 3 because we are offsetting the address by 3 ints.

Hence by doing a[0][4], we will be editing values from a[1][1]. In the backend, the subscript operator is simply the compiler generating the offset for you.